Facebook Login Error on iOS: "InvalidScopeRequested: The combination of scopes requested are not valid"
I am working on Facebook login integration for my Flutter app using the flutter_facebook_auth package. The login works fine on Android, but on iOS, I get the following error:
"InvalidScopeRequested: The combination of scopes requested are not valid"
Here’s the relevant code for the login function:

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loginFacebook() async {
    LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: [
      "public_profile",
      "email",
      "pages_show_list",
      "instagram_basic",
      "instagram_content_publish",
      "instagram_manage_insights",
      "pages_read_engagement",
      "ads_management",
      "business_management",
    ]);

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success && result.accessToken != null) {
      ClassicToken classicToken = result.accessToken as ClassicToken;

      var accessTokenMap = {
        "token": classicToken.tokenString,
        "userId": classicToken.userId,
        "expires": classicToken.expires.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        "grantedPermissions": classicToken.grantedPermissions,
        "declinedPermissions": classicToken.declinedPermissions,
      };

      return accessTokenMap;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Login failed");
    }
}

I am using the following dependency in my pubspec.yaml:
flutter_facebook_auth: ^7.0.1
I’ve requested the following permissions:

"public_profile"

"email"

"pages_show_list"

"instagram_basic"

"instagram_content_publish"

"instagram_manage_insights"

"pages_read_engagement"

"ads_management"

"business_management"


Has anyone faced this issue before or knows how to resolve it? I suspect there’s a problem with the combination of permissions on iOS. Any guidance on how to fix this would be appreciated!
Things I’ve tried:

Verified the required permissions in the Facebook Developer Console.

Followed the iOS Facebook Login configuration steps from the official documentation.


Environment:

Flutter version: Flutter 3.22.2

flutter_facebook_auth version: ^7.0.1

iOS version: 17.5


